# TypeScript 3.9 Generic Property 'disabled' does not exist on type 'T'.(2339)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

After Upgrading typescript 3.9. I'm getting this error

`Property 'disabled' does not exist on type 'T'.`

I see that Type Parameters That Extend any No Longer Act as any  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#type-parameters-that-extend-any-no-longer-act-as-any

But how can solve this?

```
export interface Item {
  name: React.ReactNode;
  value: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  renderer?;
}

interface OwnProps<T = Item> {
  data: T[];
}

export type RenderProps<T> = OwnProps<T> & Partial<SelectProps>;

export const MyComp = <T extends any>({ data }: RenderProps<T>) => {
    return <div>{data.map(item => {
            const optionDisabled = !!(item && item.disabled);
            const renderer = (item && item.renderer) || optionRenderer;
            return (
              <Select.Option disabled={optionDisabled}>
                ....
              </Select.Option>
            );
          })
   }
}</div>;
```

[Playground](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocpAD0ljmADsYkpN0k4BJFvAb3Jw4jFCCQAuOAGcYUJgHMKQgG4oANgFcJ02QqVwAJsCkoARmqQGA-JNMQIFlI31FGB1qxs65jReQC%20lEwsbBxwAPIA7owACjhgUgA8ACpwALzcvAB8cAJCBigwKJLJANoAuhSBVLTQ8DAAnmCcyG6scRAJKemZSCA5GVGx8UnJWRSUNHTwaBCMMnAAsg0AwrhgPSkANFkAFHyGhShw-pKt7lAdXWMAlOk5u4JwiUbKWXlCh0UAdCAoYLtgLx7rknp84LN5vBOjBgHMACLGMwWAw9ACEaMBwIAZNiGLxvkYTOZLDd9ODIQtXBdWD0sX04Lj8X1vtSPFAyWDPkQYBooIw4LsXsA3nw2UQoP5EgB6V5ZTng-w3MGBT4yuXkTmUchAA)

Comment: Don't extend it by any? What is even the purpose of that?

Comment: It's `.tsx` If you don't have extends it won't work. Because compiler treats this as a React element.  `<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how you use that component, but since you want to access props of `Item` it would make sense to constraint the generic type to that e.g.

```
export const MyComp = <T extends Item>({ data }: RenderProps<T>) => (
  <div>{
    data.map(item => {
      const optionDisabled = !!(item && item.disabled);
      const renderer = (item && item.renderer);
      return (<div>{renderer}</div>);
    })
   }
   </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you depend on `T` being an `Item`. Tell TypeScript about it:

```
export const MyComp = <T extends Item>({ data }: RenderProps<T>) => (
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but It didn't work same error. Updated playground link.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `RenderProps` determines the type of `OwnProps` in this instance, and in `MyComp`, `<T>` is not guaranteed to be of type `Item` (it extends `any`), the entries in the `data` array cannot be guaranteed to be of type `Item`, even though you have specified `<T = Item>` in the interface definition of `OwnProps`. As I have no idea what the use case is here, I can't know what solution will keep the functionality you need. But, seeing as you are assuming that `item` will have the property, it can't hurt to take Murat Karagöz's advice and constrain the type.

As an aside, I would recommend you use the optional chaining operator (`?.`) combined with the nullish coalescing operator (`??`) for better readability. Given that item cannot be nullish (it's properties are only accessed if the loop is entered, guaranteeing its existence), you do not need to check for this.

```
export const MyComp = <T extends Item>({ data }: RenderProps<T>) => (
  <div>{
    data.map(item => {
      const optionDisabled = item.disabled ?? false;
      const renderer = item.renderer ?? optionRenderer;
      return (<div>{renderer}</div>);
    })
   }
   </div>
);
```